# Configure GlassFish 3 for mobile?

Tags: mobile, glassfish

I have a JSF application deployed on GlassFish 
I am able to access the application from another computer 
When I try to access the application from a mobile device (iPod Touch) , I got this error telling the server couldn't be found
The iPod is connected on Internet via my home router. Exactly as the other computers

Is there anything to configure in glassfish ?

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find my solution :

The URL to access my web application is something like:
http://mymachinename:port/ApplicationName

PC can resolve DNS
iPod / iPad is not able to resolve the DNS

When I use the IP address instead of the machine name, everything works fine

Hope it will help someone else